# QGIS not recognising field names in first row

Tags: qgis, csv

For some reason, when I add a CSV as a delimited text layer QGIS is not recognizing field names in the first row. This has only been happening the last week or so. I am pulling my hair out.

Below is a screenshot of the csv and a screenshot from QGIS. As you can see QGIS is actually reading row 2 (the first row of data) as the field names.

[image: CSV file][image: QGIS screenshot]

Comment: My guess is there are some characters in the name causing issues.  First suspect would be the % sign, then maybe the brackets and the dash.

Answer (score 7):

Likely stating the obvious here, but just a sanity check, the `Number of header lines to discard` is set to zero, yeah?
[image: Field Options]

Comment: OMG - cant believe I overlooked this! Somehow I had the number of header lines to discard set to 1......

Comment: I''ve *never* done anything like that!  ;)